# Calculating arguments of complex numbers: Mistake on Wikipedia?

Tags: complex-analysis

So I wanted to write out the $\arg$ of a complex number (when the branch cut is the negative real axis) and then I compared my finding with Wikipedia but it's not the same.

Concretely, for $z$ in the second quadrant we have a picture like this:

[image]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computation) states that the argument is

$$ \arg ( x + iy) = \arctan y/x + \pi$$

I do get the same result as Wikipedia for the case $x<0,y<0$.

So my question is:

> Is this a mistake on Wikipedia or am I missing something?

Comment: $arg(x+iy) = \arctan(y/x)$ if $x > 0$, and $arg(-(x+iy)) =arg(x+iy) +  \pi +(2 k \pi) =  \arctan(y/x) + \pi$ when $x > 0$, i.e. $arg(x+iy) =arg(-(x+iy)) +  \pi =  \arctan(y/x) + \pi$ when $x < 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x <0$, $y>0$, you have
$$
\left|\frac yx\right|=-\frac yx.
$$
The arctan is odd, so both expressions are equal.